# How to change Flutter Module's Directory

Tags: android, flutter, module

When I created a flutter module through the command "flutter create -t module..." and I forgot to use "cd.." to change the directory of the root folder, for me it is "C:\Projects" and it created the module inside my Android Project Directory, which is "C:\Projects\MyAndroidApp", How do I change the directory? and is it okay to have the flutter module inside 'MyAndroidApp' ?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's ok Module inside root folder of your project. And to move, i think is just move folder and change path inside pubspec.yaml

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, should i keep it inside the root folder or move it out? The tutorials i see they keep the module outside the Android Project Folder.

Comment: Oh really? Haha, I aways put module in root folder

Comment: I think my comment is not too safe, haha

Comment: So, how do i take it out from my project folder? i checked the pubspec.yaml file there isn't anything related to changing directory.

Comment: I never did this without Android Studio, but I think it can help you: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Comment: It doesn't have the information i need, i just want to move the flutter module folder out of my project

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the project folder of the module to the intended location. This shouldn't cause much issues unless you're referencing the module on a Flutter project, which you might just need to update its path.